# Object.entries().map() not returning with output

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code that is not returning the output as expected.  I know that .forEach() does not produce any output, but as far as I'm aware .map() does.  Any thoughts as to where I went wrong?

```js
function getErrorMessages(data) {
  if (data.validation !== undefined) {
    Object.entries(data.validation).map(item => {
      return (
        <div key={item[0]} className="error">
          {item[0]} {item[1]}
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
  if (data.invalid !== undefined) {
    Object.entries(data.invalid).map(item => {
      return (
        <div key={item[0]} className="error">
          {item[0]} {item[1]}
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
}

const ErrorOutput = ({ errorInfo }) => {
  return <div className="error-output">{getErrorMessages(errorInfo)}</div>;
};
```

Comment: You might want to `return` the mapped result?

Comment: @JonasWilms is that not what the return() statement is for within the function?

Comment: @pingeyeg that is just returning value to map not out of `getErrorMessage`

Comment: No, that `return`s back to the `.map` code, that will then build up an array based on the returned value, and return that to the outer code.

Comment: Add `return Object.entries()`.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  I needed to assign that statement to a const and then return that at the end.  I'm seeing the output now.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

i think you are just missing setting a variable to the mapped object

```
const theMappedObjects = Object.entries(data.validation).map(item => {
        return (
            <div key={item[0]} className='error'>
                {item[0]} {item[1]}
            </div>
        );
```

or

```
return Object.entries(data.validation).map(item => {
            return (
                <div key={item[0]} className='error'>
                    {item[0]} {item[1]}
                </div>
            );
```